# Python: count length of word

Tags: python

I currently have this for assignment:

```
word = input("Please enter a word: ")

print("The length of " + word + " is " + len(word = int(word)))
```

It runs and I enter `Lilith Qua`

I run into an error said that:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Lilith Qua'
```

Is there away to fix this?

Comment: What do you expect `len(word = int(word))` to do? `, len(word)` is sufficient.

Comment: By the way it's better practice to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) rather than concatenation.  `print("The length of {} is {}".format(word, len(word)))` it also takes care of conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert the int to string before you concatenate.

You have to use

```
print("The length of " + word + " is " + str(len(word)))
```

String formatting can also be used as,

```
print("The length of %s is %d"%(word,len(word)))
```

Here,

- `%s` is for string
- `%d` is for int

Comment: print("The length of " + word + " is " + str(len(word))) is the right answer
Thank you. You help me out.